# Expected parsed RequestPath in request attribute "org.springframework.web.util.ServletRequestPathUtils.PATH"

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

We have a java application based on the spring boot 3.1.4 and Spring 6.0.12. Sometimes customer sent some indentical requests concurrently to our service. And one of the request would fail to be processed. The application sent back the 500 status code.    The Kibana shows the corresponding error log like below.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected parsed RequestPath in request attribute "org.springframework.web.util.ServletRequestPathUtils.PATH".
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:222)
    at org.springframework.web.util.ServletRequestPathUtils.getParsedRequestPath(ServletRequestPathUtils.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.PathPatternsRequestCondition.getMatchingCondition(PathPatternsRequestCondition.java:192)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfo.getMatchingCondition(RequestMappingInfo.java:407)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.getMatchingMapping(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.getMatchingMapping(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:68)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.addMatchingMappings(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:447)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:407)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:382)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:68)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:505)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1275)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:527)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:614)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:110)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:67)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:365)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:131)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCache
```

By checking the spring boot source code, the attribute "org.springframework.web.util.ServletRequestPathUtils.PATH" is actually set before DispatcherServlet::doDispatch. see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/d6c9ed200ab9f753940d696c9b0ce2369ebc6e92/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.java#L975. So We have no clue why this request attribute is lost before the invocation of PathPatternsRequestCondition::getMatchingCondition. Does anybody has the idea? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do here? Because I think the source code is correct :D

Comment: The error log describes that the request attribute "org.springframework.web.util.ServletRequestPathUtils.PATH" is missed. But from the spring source code , we can see the attribute is set directly before the doDispatch is called. So We want to find out why the attribute no longer exist.